# updating markers in googlemaps api v3 wth node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, serial-port, socket.io, google-maps-markers

So, I have this app that will receive text messages using serialport.
When a message is received, first the database will be searched for the phone number the SMS was received from,if the number is registered in the table "devices" then it will do the rest of the process...

Now, if the device IS registered in "devices" then it will analyse the rest of the SMS and save its coordinates to the table "monitoreo_actual", where the app will search for all the coordinates to display them as markers in a map.

This is the code i'm using for that purpose.

```
var marker = new Array();
var key;
var map = null;
socket.on('location', function(locations){
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.192),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

  for(i=0; i< locations.length; i++ ) {
    var key = locations[i]['idDispositivo'];
    marker[Number(key)] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['latitud'], locations[i]['longitud']),
                    map: map,
                    title: String(locations[i]['idDispositivo']),
                    });
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load');

});
```

Each time a device sends new coordinates, the marker for that device will be updated without reloadig the siteand that part works great because of the following code. However, there can be a situation where a device that IS registered in the database is going to send its coordinates for the first time, and in that case it still doesn't have a marker, so I have to add the marker without reloading, and that is the part that still doesn't work. I have tried many ways and so far, depending on what I try, it might either NOT load the new marker, or load the new marker and delete the rest. The following code is what I've been trying to use to update or add a new marker.

```
socket.on('location update', function(data){
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.192),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mark = marker[data['idDispositivo']];
    if(mark){
      mark.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitud'],data['longitud']));
    }else{
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
      marker[Number(data['idDispositivo'])] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitud'],data['longitud']),
                    map: map,
                    title: String(data['idDispositivo']),
                  });
    }
});
```

Updating an existing marker works, however, if anyone could help me add the new marker without having to reload the site that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i tried for 2 days and couldn't solve it, I asked the question and solved it 11 minutes later, but just now i remembered to answer it... the error was the line..

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
```

...after the "else" in the second code sample.

By setting "map" value to new google.maps.Map(...), it's like i'm actually asking the browser to request the whole map all over again, and since it's outside the first code sample, then it doesn't load the rest of the markers. So the second code sample changes to this...

```
socket.on('location update', function(data){
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.192),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mark = marker[data['idDispositivo']];
    if(mark){
      mark.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitud'],data['longitud']));
    }else{
      marker[Number(data['idDispositivo'])] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitud'],data['longitud']),
                    map: map,
                    title: String(data['idDispositivo']),
                  });
    }
});
```